Qual a origem da expressão «cor de burro quando foge»?
Qual a origem da expressão «cor de burro quando foge»?
Exemplo:


De que cor é aquele carro, mãe?
Aquele carro é cor de burro quando foge.


Ou seja, tem uma cor estranha.

A tua pesquisa?

A expressão «cor de burro quando foge» designa uma cor difícil de ser definida. Há quem diga que a expressão surge por deturpação de uma outra, que é «Corra do burro quando foge».
Segundo a minha pesquisa não faz sentido, acho que é novamente um mito que surgiu por ai.
A primeira vez que encontro essa expressão é em 1762 no livro «Historia abbreviada de Alexandre Magno»:

E aparece 30 vezes no século XIX e 388 vezes no século XX.
A expressão «Corra do burro quando foge» aparece pela primeira vez em 1998 no livro «Século de favela» e depois aparece algumas vezes no século XXI a corrigir a expressão «cor de burro quando foge».
O ciberdúvidas sugere uma explicação que pode ser plausivel, mas sem certezas, é o melhor que consegui até agora:

[...] não será mais plausível pensar que "cor de burro" seja expressão
antiga ligada ao facto de burrus, em latim, querer dizer "ruço" ou
"avermelhado"(por causa da bebida). Isto, independentemente de burro
ter ou não como étimo aquele termo latino, questão que os dicionários
não dão por assente. É curioso, aliás, que "ruço" seja termo
comummente aplicado a equídeos, inclusive a burros.
Ora, se se admitisse  esta origem de "cor de burro", seria fácil
explicar a expressão actual, "cor de burro quando foge", como variação
humorística posterior à perda de consciência de que "burro", na
expressão original, designava efetivamente uma cor.

